# C++: The while loop in my claculator is blocking switch case

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and English isn't my first language so excuse any confusion on my part.
In the calculator I'm trying to build, I made it so that it can handle 'invalid' input and loop right back to my menu, however now the 'right' input in my switch case doesn't work anymore. Can someone tell me why that is?

Code below

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>


int main ()
{
    cout << "Calculator [v.1.0]" << endl;
    cout << "(c) 2021 <Chayenne van der Erf>" << endl << endl;

Menu:
     cout << "Kies een bewerking en druk op Enter:" << endl;
     cout << "1. Optellen              2. Aftrekken" << endl;
     cout << "3. Vermenigvuldigen      4. Delen" <<endl;
     cout << "5. Kwadraat              6. Worteltrekken" <<endl;
     cout << "7. Reciproke             8. Logarithme" <<endl;
     cout << "0. Exit" << endl << endl;

    int Bewerking;
    cout << "Bewerking: ";
    cin >> Bewerking;
    while (!(cin >> Bewerking)) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << endl << "Ongeldige input. Alleen getallen toegestaan." << endl << endl;

    cout << "___" << endl; goto Menu;}

    cout << endl;

    switch (Bewerking) {
    case 1:
     cout << "Optellen";
        break;
    case 2:
     cout << "Aftrekken";
        break;
    case 3:
     cout << "Vermenigvuldigen";
        break;
    case 4:
     cout << "Delen";
        break;
    case 5:
     cout << "Kwadraat";
        break;
    case 6:
     cout << "Worteltrekken";
        break;
    case 7:
     cout << "Reciproke";
        break;
    case 8:
     cout<< "Logarithme";
        break;
    case 0:
    exit (0);

    default: cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;}

    cout << endl;

    if (Bewerking == 1) {
     double A, B;
     double antwoord;

    cout << "Enter een waarde: ";
    cin >> A;
      if (!cin.fail()) {

    cout << "Enter een waarde: ";
    cin >> B;
    if (!cin.fail()) {

    antwoord = A + B;
    cout << endl;
        cout << "= " << antwoord << endl << endl; } } }

    else if (Bewerking == 2) {
     double A, B;
     double antwoord;

    cout << "Enter een waarde: ";
    cin >> A;
    if (!cin.fail()) {

    cout << "Enter een waarde: ";
    cin >> B;
    if (!cin.fail()) {

    antwoord = A - B;
    cout << endl;
        cout << "= " << antwoord << endl << endl;

     cout << "___" << endl; goto Menu; } } }


     else if (Bewerking == 3) {
     double A, B;
     double antwoord;

    cout << "Enter een waarde: ";
    cin >> A;
     if (!cin.fail()) {

    cout << "Enter een waarde: ";
    cin >> B;
     if (!cin.fail()) {

    antwoord = A * B;
    cout << endl;
        cout << "= " << antwoord << endl << endl;

     cout << "___" << endl; goto Menu; } } }

        else if (Bewerking == 4) {
     double A, B;
     double antwoord;

    cout << "Enter een waarde: ";
    cin >> A;
     if (!cin.fail()) {

    cout << "Enter een waarde: ";
    cin >> B;
     if (!cin.fail()) { cout << endl;

     while (B == 0)

     {cout << "Delen door 0 is niet mogelijk." << endl;
     cout << endl;
     cout << "Enter een andere waarde: ";
     cin >> B; }

     {antwoord = A / B;}
     cout << endl;
     cout << "= " << antwoord << endl << endl;

     cout << "___" << endl; goto Menu; } } }


    else if (Bewerking == 5) {
     double X;
     double antwoord;
     cout << "Enter waarde: ";
     cin >> X;
        if (!cin.fail()) {
     antwoord = X * X;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "= " << antwoord << endl << endl;

     cout << "___" << endl; goto Menu; } }

    else if (Bewerking == 6) {
     double X;
     double antwoord;
     cout << "Enter waarde: ";
     cin >> X;
        if (!cin.fail()) {
     antwoord = pow (X,0.5);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "= " << antwoord << endl << endl;

     cout << "___" << endl; goto Menu; } }

        else if (Bewerking == 7) {
     double X;
     double antwoord;
     cout << "Enter waarde: ";
     cin >> X;
        if (!cin.fail()) {
     antwoord = 1 / X;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "= " << antwoord << endl << endl;

     cout << "___" << endl; goto Menu; } }

        else if (Bewerking == 8) {
     double X;
     double antwoord;
     cout << "Enter waarde: ";
     cin >> X;
        if (!cin.fail()) {
     antwoord = log (X);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "= " << antwoord << endl << endl;

     cout << "___" << endl; goto Menu; } }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bad indentation :(

Comment: Why using `goto`? maybe you are a victim of spaghetti  code.

Comment: Your code is less readable and bad-indented.

Comment: `cin >> Bewerking; while (!(cin >> Bewerking))` So why are you reading the same thing twice in a row? Do you expect your user to type it twice in a row?

Comment: @MikeCAT I'm an absolute amateur I learned all this a week ago :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `while (!(cin >> Bewerking)) {` you keep assigning values into `Bewerking` until it's empty - but you are still assigning this value to `Bewerking` - effectively overriding the "good" value.

While there are many other issues with the code - to solve the specific issue in the question - you need to keep the last value of `Bewerking` - and use this instead of the overridden variable.